# What is an easy way to enable Mini-profiler for a session only?

Tags: .net, session, mvc-mini-profiler

I have a simple web form application that uses a masterpage.

I followed the instructions on how to get mini-profiler working. I get all the stats OK. Now I do not really know how to toggle it on or off.

I thought of using a query string and look for it `Application_BeginRequest` - If it is there just use the profiler the whole session.... OK- Session is not loaded at that stage and if use the `Application_AcquireRequestState` and a static variable it loads it many many times and the profiler does work sometimes, sometimes not and I do not know why?

The simple way I have now is.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MiniProfiler profiler = null;

            if (Request.QueryString["p"] != null)
            {

                profiler = MiniProfiler.Start();

                using (profiler.Step("Application_BeginRequest"))
                {
                }
            }


        }
```

So that works ok but i have to add a query param on each request. Not good. I never used `global.asax` before so I am not 100% sure how it all works down there.

What is the best way I can set a variable for a pre defined time so the profiler will always load when I turn it on in a secret way?

---

Edit and solution to my problem

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MiniProfiler profiler = null;
            if (Request.Cookies["profiler"] != null)
            {
                profiler = MiniProfiler.Start();

                using (profiler.Step("Application_BeginRequest"))
                {
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you added MiniProfiler via the MiniProfiler.MVC3 package, then it adds a C# file for your convenience in configuring it: look in `App_Start\MiniProfiler.cs`, looking in particular at `Init` which has the code to decide whether to start profiling (`request.IsLocal` is the default)

In your case, I would suggest checking for a cookie in the *start* condition, and checking your more complete "am I a developer, or just someone who heard about a special cookie" in the *end* condition; in particular, if you call `MiniProfiler.Stop(false)`, then all the data is discarded. Your "turn it on in a secret way" and "pre defined time" are then all achieved cheaply via the cookie, with the "am I a developer" there to make sure that it can't be abused just by setting a cookie.

Comment: Hi- I used `nuget` and it just added the reference library. But I did not think of cookies! Yes- That worked and now I can control it. Thank you!